# Comparison of addresses of NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification not equal to a null pointer is always true

Tags: ios, objective-c, ensembles

I get this warning in Xcode

```
comparison of addresses of NSUbiquitycontainerDidChangeNotification not equal to a null pointer is always true
```

it is in the Core Data Ensembles Framework in

```
CDEICloudFileSystem.m
```

in

```
- (void)addUbiquityContainerNotificationObservers  {

 [self removeUbiquityContainerNotificationObservers];

/// in this line 
if (&NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification != NULL) {
///

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    ubiquityIdentityObserver = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        __strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        [strongSelf stopMonitoring];
        [strongSelf willChangeValueForKey:@"identityToken"];
        [strongSelf didChangeValueForKey:@"identityToken"];
    }];
  }
}
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: Unless you are attempting to support iOS 5, there is no need to check for the `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification` constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote that code. As several have pointed out, it is there to ensure that the `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification` symbol exists before using it. Before iOS 6, that notification did not exist.

The code is several years old, and iOS 5 is not supported now in the framework, so I will remove the check.

**Update**
Turns out the check could not be removed, because we still support OS X 10.7. So I added #pragmas to silence the warning instead.

Comment: Thanks ! My app is iOS only and supports iOS7 and later, no OS X - so I am just gonna remove the line... !?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `&NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification` is the address of the variable and it cannot be NULL.
The condition `if (&NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification != NULL)` always values true and Xcode warns you that the line is useless.

Comment: The address can be `NULL` if run under iOS 5 or earlier.

Comment: I support iOS7 and later. So I can just delete the line ? It s just, it s not my code, and I am afraid to mess with the framework :/

Comment: Yes you have to delete `if (&NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification != NULL) {`

Comment: @JeremyVizzini It's not that you have to delete it. It's that it's pointless in this case.

Comment: @Kreuzberg If you prefer not removing the code from the implementation file, write the expression as follows: ((&NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification) != NULL). This will remove the warning in Xcode 7. Just another option.